# Why is Git exclude operator excluding all commits, even for commit with no descendants

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a simple repo with four commits

[image]

```
git git:(master) git log --pretty=reference
9843ccb (Adding file2, 2022-08-15)
6819130 (Committing the text update, 2022-08-03)
e269435 (Moving file1 to file1a, 2022-08-03)
14181db (First new file in repo, 2022-08-03)
```

If I do `git log` on the most recent commit 9843ccb, the result lists all four commits, because it shows all commits reachable from the specified commit, which includes all the ancestors.

```
git git:(master) git log 9843ccb --pretty=reference
9843ccb (Adding file2, 2022-08-15)
6819130 (Committing the text update, 2022-08-03)
e269435 (Moving file1 to file1a, 2022-08-03)
14181db (First new file in repo, 2022-08-03)
```

and if I do `git log` on the oldest commit, the result lists only one commit, because that commit has no ancestors. So far so good.

```
git git:(master) git log 14181db --pretty=reference
14181db (First new file in repo, 2022-08-03)
```

My problem is in understanding the **exclude** operator '^'.
If I exclude the most recent commit, then I should see no results, because it excludes all commits reachable from this commit, which is all of them, as they are all ancestors. And that is what happens.

```
git git:(master) git log ^9843ccb --pretty=reference
git git:(master)
```

But if I exclude the oldest commit, I would not expect its descendants to be also excluded. However, that is what is happening.

```
git git:(master) git log ^14181db --pretty=reference
git git:(master)
```

Why is this? What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3):

A prefixed caret, or exclude syntax (`^abc123`), is short for (`--not abc123`) and is intended to be used along with [other revisions](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_multiple_points).

For example, `git log abc ^def` could be spoken as:

> Show me all commits reachable by `abc` that are not reachable by `def`.

If you don't use it with other revisions, for example, `git log ^def`, it could be spoken as:

> Show me all commits reachable by nothing, that are not reachable by `def`.

Thus, no commits will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

It's a quirk, if you don't specify any revs the convenience commands will add `HEAD` by default, but if you do, they won't. That convenience check doesn't check whether you gave only exclusion specs, any non-option arg bypasses adding a default. You can say `git log 14181db.. --pretty=reference` instead.